# Copy a macro from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to excel VBA. My problem is I have to copy a macro from one existing workbook to another which is created at run time. So that the copied macro should run on that created workbook. Since am new I have no idea to do it. I am using excel 2007.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets say that book1 is the source book, and book2 is the output then

Try

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyMacro()
    '// Source 
    Workbooks("book1").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("module1").Export ("c:\temp\mymod.bas")
    '// Output
    Workbooks("book2").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import ("c:\temp\mymod.bas")
End Sub
```

Comment: if I understood the OP, the request was how to copy the "macro" to the new workbook.

Comment: Actually the workbook is created at runtime. So i want to paste the code in workbook which is created at runtime.

Comment: It gives Error saying "Method Export of object _VBComponets failed"

Answer (score -1):

You need to first set a reference to the VBA Extensibility library and then enable programmatic access to the VBA Project (can be done under "Options>Trust Center>Trust Center Settings>Macro Settings Trust Access to the VBA project object model).

Best explanation on the internet for doing this is given at: [Cpearson.com](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx)